# Import XML to MySql- Warning code=1263

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm trying to export XML file to the database MySQL through MySQL console.
I'm using the following commands:

1. `\.C:/..../dbmysql.sql`
2. `LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:..../docente.xml'
    INTO TABLE DOCENTE;`

After this it gives me this warning:

> Warning|1263|Column Set to default value;Null supplied to NOT NULL columns

How can I fix this?

Comment: "Null supplied to NOT NULL columns" is the key, you need to check your table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me google it for you, using keyword "`mysql warning 1263 Null supplied to NOT NULL columns`", here is one that relevant  :

> "The warning message only occurs when a column is not null constrained and the column name fails to match an XML tag attribute in the source file. No error or warning is raised when a column isn’t not null constrained under the same scenario." [[MacLochlainns Weblog](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/09/26/load-xml-local-infile/)]

According to the article, you'll need to make sure that XML tags name for column match the columns name in MySQL table in case-sensitive way.

Comment: The xml exported from Sybase used the tag COLUMN..I just changed it for the tag FIELD and it worked perfectly.
Thanks for your help